# Finding kth smallest element using Java

Tags: java, recursion, partition

I'm trying to make a code for finding k<sup>th</sup> smallest element using partitions.

When I run this code, I think it works pretty fine for less than 5 numbers, but whenever I use bigger data--like over 100 or 10000 datas--and try to find k<sup>th</sup> number, it keeps giving me back `java.lang.StackOverflowError` message, or just simply complete wrong answer.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class test2 {        

    public static int partition(double arr[], int begin, int end){          

        int pivotIndex = begin; 
        double pivot = arr[pivotIndex];                 
        begin++; 

        int p = begin; 
        int r = (int) end; 
        while (p <= r){
            while (p <= r && arr[p] < pivot)
                p++; 

            while(p<=r && arr[r] > pivot)
                r--;            
            if (p > r){
                swap(arr, pivotIndex, r);} 
            else {swap(arr, p, r);
            }               
            }
        return r;}              
    public static void swap(double[] arr, int a, int b){        

          if (a <= b){  
            double temp;
            temp = arr[a];
            arr[a] = arr[b];
            arr[b] = temp;  }           
    }       

    public static double selection(double[] arr, int begin, int end, int k){

        int pivotIndex = begin; 
        int i = pivotIndex; 
        pivotIndex = partition(arr, begin, end); 


        if (i == k-1){
            return arr[(k-1)]; 

        }
        else if (i > k-1 ){ 
            return selection(arr, begin, i-1, k); 
        }
        else{

            return selection(arr, i+1, end, k-i);   }}          


    public static void main (String[] args) {


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Selection Test\n"); 
        int n, i; 

        System.out.println("Enter number of elements"); 
            n = scan.nextInt(); 

        double arr[] = new double [n]; 


       System.out.println("\nEnter "+ n +" elements");
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)   


            arr[i] = scan.nextDouble();         
            System.out.println("\nEnter the kth smallest element you'd like to find");   
            int k = scan.nextInt();

            kthsmall(arr, k);

             System.out.println(arr[k-1
                                    ]);          

    }       
    public static void kthsmall(double[] arr, int k){
        selection(arr, 0, arr.length -1, k);}
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could tell me where my mistakes are.

Comment: To find the kth smallest number in an array list, I'd sort it using built in methods, and then pick the kth element. That would be O(n log (n)).

Comment: when using recursion on big data set , you can expect getting Stack overflow .... every recursion can be transformed to iterative so I would try that

Comment: Yup, I totally agree sorting would be make this much easier:) However what I'm assigned to do here is simply finding kth element, without sorthing.:(